# I can't get Bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar-fixed-top to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been using Bootstrap navbars for five years now. This is the first time I haven't been able to make it work. I have even copied the html right from the Bootstrap site and I can't get it to work in any browser nor in dreamweaver. I have been searching for a solution for two days now and cannot find one anywhere.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Fixed Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
        <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have been searching for a sample of your attempted code and cannot find one anywhere

Comment: Can you please add the code sample.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h  ... Check This

Comment: I have added the code. It's only been modified to connect to the .js and .css on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you used `container` instead of `container-fluid`

The [W3 documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) should work.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=v

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body style="height:1500px">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>
</body>
```